# JsMockito stubbing a field

Tags: javascript, mocking

I have a simple object that I am mocking, assume something like this:

```
function MyObject() {
    this.SomeVariable = "some-value";
    this.SomeFunction = function() { ... };
}
```

Now I want to mock the variable, which I was doing:

```
var mockedObject = mock(MyObject);
when(mockedObject).SomeVariable.thenReturn("some-other-value");
```

However it tells me that I cannot use thenReturn() on this... cant remember the exact error but does anyone know a way around this? Or should I just do:

```
var mockedObject = mock(MyObject);
mockedObject.SomeVariable = "some-other-value";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only stub or verify interactions (function calls).  Because "SomeVariable" is an attribute in the object, not a function in the object you cannot stub or verify uses of it.

So your conclusion is correct; you should simply provide the value you want as an attribute of the object:

```
var mockedObject = mock(MyObject);
mockedObject.SomeVariable = "some-other-value";
```

An alternative, if it's your own code, is to change the original object to use a "getter" style function instead, e.g.:

```
function MyObject() {
    this.SomeVariable = function() { return "some-value"; };
    this.SomeFunction = function() { ... };
}
```

For true "objects" this is often a better approach than using attributes.

Comment: The actual object is basically an enum, you raise a good point that maybe they should be functions though... thanks for the answer!